# Multiple queries by date in the same row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to sum the daily sales of each product ASIN. Sounds easy but I can`t do it.

On the left, you can see the data. At the right, the empty table that I need to create.

[image: image example]

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(K2:M; "select K,sum(M) where M is not null group by K pivot L")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an IF statement on the columns that you want summed.
For your example, it would be something like this:

```
in Cell P2
=IF($L2 = P$1, $M2, 0)
```

This translates to

```
If ((the text in column L row 2 = the text in p1), take the units from column m row 2, else take 0)
```

The `$` are there to indicate you always want that column/row. So we always want to evaluate column L at the start and Row 1 in the comparison.

Then at the last row of the sheet you have a SUM function for the column

```
=SUM(P2:P100)
or whatever the end is
```

Working example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zhQMV6o1tF2P_kWbXDPdnVKzYnd-Dsvg2h7YiHWSaNI/edit?usp=sharing